# Trying to check a condition for every element in a list of integers

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a method to check whether or not every element of a list is a factor of the parameter.

Here's what I have:

```
def factorall(x):
if all(x % num  for num in nums) == 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

(In this case nums is a list of the integers from 1 to 10)

However, this returns true for any number. I'm assuming this happens because it is only checking 1 and then returning True, but shouldn't all() be checking for every element of the list before returning True?

I'm a bit unfamiliar with all() so I probably implemented it incorrectly. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, there's no good reason to do `if foo: return True` `else: return False` when `foo` is already a boolean. You're just making your code longer (and harder to read and maintain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the comparison inside the `all` function, or simply remove it, and use negation of the result `x % num`:

```
def factorall(x):
    return all(not x % num for num in nums)
```

The return statement works same as:

```
return all(x % num == 0 for num in nums)
```

I agree that the 2nd one seems clearer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about why I'd need to include not, though. Could you explain? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: @RAF1940. Sorry to confuse. If `num` is a factor of `x`, `x % num` will be `0`. Since we are using `all()` function, we do a `not`, to make the result `True` for factor. And if all numbers are factor, then all value will be `True` in `all()`.

Comment: @RAF1940. This is similar to using `x % num == 0`. Both of them will be `True` if `num` is a factor of `x`.

Comment: `x % num == 0` is far more meaningful here than `not x % num` in my opinion

Answer (score 7):

you should use `not any` instead of all

```
def factorall(x):
    return not any(x%num for num in nums) #if any of these is a value other than 0
```

or if you want it like you currently have it

```
def factorall(x):
    return all(x%num==0 for num in nums)
```

Comment: I'm wondering if any use case of `all` could be implemented with `any` and if so, wouldn't it always be better?

Comment: demorgans laws say yes any expression can be inverted... but i dont think its always better it depends on what you are trying to express http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Answer (score 2):

```
def factorall(x):
    if all(x % num == 0  for num in nums):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: missed that there was no 0 inside the all :(